# Typing dimers wave function

Tags: typography

I need to type the Hamiltonian for Quantum Dimer Model given below.[image: QDM]
The problem is typing the dimers "two bullets connected by single bond" along with the adjustable bra and ket vectors.

Can anyone make comments on how to type these dimer wave functions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @ Werner, No, because I could not figure out how to code those dimers.

Comment: Try using TikZ.

Comment: Note that while display math is centered, the baselines are not **at** the center.  The offset is about `0.5\ht\strutbox-0.5\dp\strutbox`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` command from the `mathtools` package to define `\bra` and `\ket`. Note the usage:

```
\ket[<optional size command>]{<contents>}
```

I would avoid the `physics` package which defines these but has some issues.

For the dimers I suggest using `tikz` and defining each as its own `tikzpicture`. You can adjust line thickness, scale, etc. however you like.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz, mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\bra}{\langle}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ket}{\lvert}{\rangle}

\tikzset{dot/.style={draw, thin, circle, fill, outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=1mm}}

\newcommand{\plaqx}{\tikz[baseline=.5ex, scale=.4]{
    \draw(0,0)node[dot](A){}--(60:1)node[dot](B){}(1,0)node[dot](D){}--++(60:1)node[dot](C){};
    \draw[line width=1.5pt](A)--(D)(B)--(C);
    }
}
\newcommand{\plaqy}{\tikz[baseline=.5ex, scale=.4]{
    \draw[line width=1.5pt](0,0)node[dot](A){}--(60:1)node[dot](B){}(1,0)node[dot](D){}--++(60:1)node[dot](C){};
    \draw(A)--(D)(B)--(C);
    }
}
\newcommand{\linka}{\tikz[baseline=-.5ex, scale=.4]{
    \draw(0,0)node[dot](A){}--(1,0)node[dot](B){};
    }
}
\newcommand{\linkb}{\tikz[baseline=-.5ex, scale=.4]{
    \draw[line width=1.5pt](0,0)node[dot](A){}--(1,0)node[dot](B){};
    }
}


\begin{document}

\begin{align}
H=-t&\sum_r\Bigl(\ket[\Big]{\plaqy}\bra[\Big]{\plaqx}+\textup{h.c.}\Bigr)\notag\\
+V&\sum_r\Bigl(\ket[\Big]{\plaqy}\bra[\Big]{\plaqy}+\ket[\Big]{\plaqx}\bra[\Big]{\plaqx}\Bigr)\notag\\
-h&\sum_l\Bigl(\ket[\Big]{\linkb}\bra[\Big]{\linka}+\textup{h.c.}\Bigr)\notag\\
-\mu&\sum_l\Bigl(\ket[\Big]{\linkb}\bra[\Big]{\linkb}\Bigr),
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for the answer but mostly for the "has some issues" understatement `:-D`